# elastic beanstalk cron seem dosen't working

Tags: python, linux, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a website using Elastic Beanstalk.

After crawling every hour and saving it as a .txt file, when the user accesses it, the .txt file loads but it doesn't seem to work.

When connected, only the .txt file from the initial deployment is loaded.

The current .zip configuration is

```
-.ebextensions
     >cron-linx.config
-static
-templates
-application.py
-Enterprise.txt
-requirements.txt
-test.py
```

cron-linux.config

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            */5 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            python3 /var/app/current/test.py

            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

test.py

```
import time
now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')
f=open('Enterprise.txt','w',encoding='UTF-8')
f.write(str(now))
f.close()
```

What should I do? For Linux, I would appreciate it if you could explain it in detail, as I only know simple commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cron` job will run under `root` user and will create `Enterprise.txt` in the `/root` folder. However, you application runs under `webapp` user and operates in `/var/app/current`. This explains why you can't find `Enterprise.txt` created by the `cron` (it will be in `/root`).

To rectify the issue, you could change your cron script as follows (I can **confirm** it works on `Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3`):

**cron-linux.config**

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            */5 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash
            
            exec &>> /tmp/cron_capture_log.txt

            /usr/sbin/runuser -l webapp -c 'cd /var/app/current; python3 ./test.py'

            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

Comment: You're back, my savior.
After copying and pasting your file, after 5 minutes of distribution, I watched if the web page reflected the new .txt, but nothing happened :(

Comment: Can you please login the instance and inspect the /var/app/current?

Comment: I haven't tried connecting to an Elastic beanstalk instance.
First of all, I think I've heard somewhere that a newline should be placed at the end of the .config file, so I'm putting a newline and redeploying it.

Comment: I tried newline, but to no avail. Let's log in to the instance and go to /var/app/current.

Comment: I added a key pair to the current instance, but my laptop doesn't support ssh, so I'll be able to tell you after about an hour to desktop.

Comment: @김준우 I can confirm, something is wrong with the answer. The file is not being created. I look into in on my own EB environment.

Comment: I also checked and I don't have the /app directory in /var.

Comment: @김준우 How come? I think you said you are using Amazon Linux 2, EB environment. If its not there, then you are using old version, Amazon Linux 1?

Comment: @김준우 I modified the answer. I can confirm it works on `Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3`

Comment: This is the result of entering the "aws --version" command.
aws-cli/1.18.13 Python/2.7.18 Linux/4.14.181-108.257.amzn1 .x86_64 botocore/1.15.13

Comment: @김준우 Check in your EB console on your environment. The version is to the right of Health, under Platform python logo.

Comment: that is Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux

Comment: @김준우 So its Amazon Linux 1. My answer will no work sadly in this case :-(. There are lots of differences between AL1 and AL2.

Comment: It's very, very sad. Still, thank you for your help.

Comment: @김준우 AL1 has only few months of [its life left](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/update-on-amazon-linux-ami-end-of-life/). So maybe its good opportunity to move to AL2, as soon you will have to do it anyway probably.

Comment: I knew that for the first time. I'll try

Comment: @김준우 Worth trying. If get stack please feel free to make new questions on SO. The script is not too far from working on AL1, but I don't have AL1 EB environment to modify it again. All my EBs are on AL2.

Comment: Is the code below for debugging?

exec &>> /tmp/cron_capture_log.txt

Comment: @김준우 Yes. You can inspect the outcome of the commands, including errors, in that file.

Comment: Cron-test was currently conducted using Linux2. It was finally successful!! Thank you very much.Now, based on that code, I have to crawl every hour to save the results in a .txt file. Have a nice day.

Comment: @김준우 Glad to hear that :-) Nice day to you as well. And if you have any questions, please feel free to ask on SO :-)

Comment: I'm back. I wrote the crawl code in test.py but it didn't work. After a bit of debugging, it seems like an error that occurs because the module, such as from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, is not installed. What should I do?

Comment: @김준우 Hi. Could you make new question?. Its a new issue. Also don't forget to mention what EB platform you use, AL1 or AL2, and some code that you are trying.

Comment: I found it more appropriate to use curl and call an already existing route e.g: curl -s  http://localhost/cronjob