# How to run .py files as cronjob in aws?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron

I have a Django application which it's deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk(Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.1). I have been trying to run a .py file as a `cronjob` that works at 4 a.m every day in AWS and I have created a `.config` file into `.ebextensions` for that such as below.

**cron.config file:**

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/cron_process":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            0 4 * * * root /usr/local/bin/task_process.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/task_process.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            date > /tmp/date
            source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
            cd /var/app/current
            python Bot/run_spiders.py
            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/cron_process.bak"
```

**run_spiders.py file:**

```
from first_bot.start import startallSpiders
from .models import Spiders
import importlib

test = Spiders.objects.get(id=1)
test.spider_name = "nigdehalk"
test.save()
```

I'm trying to change an attribute of one of my objects for testing but it didn't work. Am I missing something? How can I create this cronjob?

Comment: "it didn't work" is not very specific. Why it didn't work? Any errors, timeouts, unexpected behavior?

Comment: I didn't get any error or timeout etc. however my spider_name is "nigde" and it isn't updated.

Comment: Maybe your `task_process.sh` crashes. Can you add `exec &>> /tmp/cron_capture_log.txt` to log its output as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63110056/248823). Maybe it will have some information on any errors, if there are any?

Comment: Thank you so much. I got all returns with txt now I will fix all errors.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I can provide an answer with my suggestion to log the cron output?.

Comment: Sure please do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by failure of `task_process.sh`. Normally, cron will not show error messages if  `task_process.sh` fail. To help troubleshoot the issue, you can redirect all output into a text file using:

```
exec &>> /tmp/cron_capture_log.txt
```

Subsequently, the EB config file could be:

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/cron_process":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            0 4 * * * root /usr/local/bin/task_process.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/task_process.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            exec &>> /tmp/cron_capture_log.txt

            date > /tmp/date
            source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
            cd /var/app/current
            python Bot/run_spiders.py
            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/cron_process.bak"
```

The above helps to identify issues with `task_process.sh` when running in cron.